Free disk space of Zabbix server is less than 20% on volume /var/lib
Zabbix server's /var/lib free disk space is running low:

Checking the server, the ibdata1 file is causing the problem:

How can I fix this?
Additional question:
The file named kcore is huge. What is this file?


Was there a crash at the time indicated by the kcore time?  Probably should rm it.

no crash, currently zabbix is working normally.

Check the date on the "kcore" in one of those .pngs.
